# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir

Tags: maven, cassandra, gulp, jhipster

I scaffold an app using jhipster which is microservice gateway using cassandra db and using maven to build which was building fine after scaffold.i ran gulp command to for the live reload of ui.

i made a change slighlty in navbar and home page of it.
which was also working file & made some changes in the json files of home & navbar & do some minor changes as adding the search box and other.

it failed to reload. I stop the gulp & maven & restarted them.
maven is building but again not loading the site in localhost

when i ran gulp it is showing me this error.

```
 gulp
fs.js:952
  return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), options.encoding);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/home/hartron/foodnetteam/codebase/mandi/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:952:18)
    at Object.getInstalledBinaries (/home/hartron/foodnetteam/codebase/mandi/node_modules/node-sass/lib/extensions.js:121:13)
    at foundBinariesList (/home/hartron/foodnetteam/codebase/mandi/node_modules/node-sass/lib/errors.js:20:15)
    at foundBinaries (/home/hartron/foodnetteam/codebase/mandi/node_modules/node-sass/lib/errors.js:15:5)
    at Object.module.exports.missingBinary (/home/hartron/foodnetteam/codebase/mandi/node_modules/node-sass/lib/errors.js:45:5)
    at module.exports (/home/hartron/foodnetteam/codebase/mandi/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hartron/foodnetteam/codebase/mandi/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

Could anyone tell me solution for this

Comment: Which version of node? node -v

Comment: i am using node version 6.11.1

Answer (score 420, accepted):

I sometimes also get this error when starting my gulp server. My workaround is to just run:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

And then gulp starts nicely afterward.

Comment: I was receiving the same error while trying to run a [KeystoneJS](http://keystonejs.com/getting-started/) website with `$ node keystone`, and your workaround solved the error. Thanks

Comment: I got the error 'Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '**/node_modules/node-sass/vendor', this solution helped me resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same problem in Angular project and solved by this command. New "npm install" can't fix my error. It seems a problem in old "node-sass" version. https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1918

Comment: I my case (in linux), it was necessary to pre-download the installer "nodejs node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js" then rebuild

Comment: Good to know: I had this problem on my laptop a lot when switching between different versions of node (including different versions of most node packages). I was maintaining 2 versions of a web site from the same laptop. One site was old and based on Angular and the other site was based on React. And this specific problem went away when the old site was finally replaced I no longer had to switch between the two projects on my laptop.

Comment: this worked for me. I am using webpack and I still braintree-dropin when everything stopped working! Thank you!

Answer (score 50):

Here's what worked for me

```
$npm update
$npm install
$node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js
$npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: this works for me,  except on line 3 I replaced "nodejs" with just "node"

Comment: pre-install scripts are not executed while installing. works for me too. just replaced with the global install directory:)

Comment: node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js also works too.

Comment: if you for some reason previously has run:

`npm config set ignore-scripts true`

then the node binding will not be installed. This was my issues, and running:

`node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js`

fixed my issue

Comment: yesss. What @vr_driver said. Running just `node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js` worked for me

Thanks for this!

Comment: You have literally saved my life.

Comment: Oh Man! How can I owe you a cup of coffee or a beer! I literally tried for whole day and finally your solution worked!

Answer (score 11):

For my case it helps only after doing this command:

```
node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js
```

And then there will be `/node_modules/node-sass/vendor` folder

Answer (score 10):

rebuild node-sass or just reinstall everything in case node-sass rebuild of doesn't work.

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

or

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

or

```
npm rebuild
```

or

```
npm ci
```

or
just delete node_modules manually and package-lock.json and run `npm i`

Answer (score 7):

Some files may not be available in the local version of NodeJS, and sometimes NodeJS does not send a message about it.  In this case `--force` is helpful.

```
npm install node-sass --force
```

or

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

Answer (score 7):

I just fixed this error. It was because I was trying to run the project from the wrong folder.

Comment: I had a similar issue, I had put wrong `folderPath: '/path/to/my/project/dist',` in my `vite.config.ts`. More details here https://github.com/Ssis53/vite-plugin-zip/issues/5

Answer (score 4):

The **vendor** directory is created during npm install. Try deleting your
*node_modules* and running `npm install`.

Answer (score 4):

It is a problem with older version of `node-sass`. It doesn't create `vendor folder` in `node_modules/node-sass`. I have updated the version of node-sass and it worked fine for me.

My older version of node-sass was `3.1.0`

I simply did:

> npm install node-sass@3.7.0

This should solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the config.json file. Then do the `npm install` and `npm start`.

This might give this error if you don't have this config file.

Answer (score 1):

No need to delete node modules, its because of your sass-loader version is different

1. Delete package-lock.json
2. npm uninstall node-sass --save
3. npm i node-sass --save

Answer (score 1):

1. delete the node-sass folder from node\npm-cache
2. npm rebuild node-sass

Answer (score 1):

I did the below code,

```
sudo npm rebuild node-sass
mvn clean install
```

Comment: mvn? does it work with node or with java!!

Answer (score 0):

Update your gulp-sass in package.json with new version

```
"gulp-sass": "3.1.0" // 3.1.0 or later
```

This is the link which i follow https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/508