# Error after typing in npm start in terminal

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I followed along to a video and rechecked my code to ensure I didn't have any spelling errors. But for some reason, I have an error after I type in npm start in terminal.

> kayladwilliams$ npm start > sassbootstrap@1.0.0 start /Users/kayladwilliams/Desktop/Accessibility_Website/sassbootstrap > parcel ./src/index.html Server running at localhost:1234  /Users/kayladwilliams/Desktop/Accessibility_Website/sassbootstrap/src/scss/style.css:undefined:undefined: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kayladwilliams/Desktop/Accessibility_Website/sassbootstrap/src/scss/style.css' Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kayladwilliams/Desktop/Accessibility_Website/sassbootstrap/src/scss/style.css' –

I looked into bootstrap website to see if anything is different from the website. I double checked my directory as well, along with a few other imports just don't recall which ones I found online, i have tried

1.@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
2.@import "/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
3. npm install via terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have messed up something in here or the required style.css is not available in the expected location, which is, according to [this bootstrap tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/design/72/Installing-Bootstrap-4-Tutorial) defined in the package.json file, created initially by running `npm init`.

Then run `npm i bootstrap` to install bootstrap. Then import bootstrap using `@import 'bootstrap';`.

Then run `npm install` and `npm start`. This should install bootstrap as node module and you should ne able to use bootstrap.

Maybe you need to Install a different package like bootstrap-scss or bootstrap-sass though.

Bootstraps package.json contains some additional metadata under the following keys:

- sass - path to Bootstrap’s main Sass source file
- style - path to Bootstrap’s non-minified CSS that’s been precompiled using the default settings (no customization)

Comment: Just tried this, still having the same error. I assume I was supposed to do @import 'bootstrap'; in the style.scss file. I also attempted import 'bootstrap-scss'; and import 'bootstrap-sass'; in the style.scss file.Any other suggestions? Not sure if this is a common problem.Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Corrected the @import above. Can you post the complete output here please.  Have you updated node recently. npm rebuild might help. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251645/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-scandir

Comment: I did do the @import above, for some odd reason posting the previous comment, I couldn't submit unless I took the @ symbol out of the message.I have installed the npm recently so I assume its the most up to date version. I can attach a pic of what my terminal is saying

Comment: Kaylas-MacBook-Pro:sassbootstrap kayladwilliams$ npm i bootstrap
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sassbootstrap@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN sassbootstrap@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ bootstrap@4.3.1
updated 1 package and audited 10384 packages in 3.453s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: Kaylas-MacBook-Pro:sassbootstrap kayladwilliams$ npm install
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sassbootstrap@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN sassbootstrap@1.0.0 No repository field.

audited 10384 packages in 3.263s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: Kaylas-MacBook-Pro:sassbootstrap kayladwilliams$ npm start

> sassbootstrap@1.0.0 start /Users/kayladwilliams/Desktop/Accessibility_Website/sassbootstrap
> parcel ./src/index.html

Server running at http://localhost:1234 
  /Users/kayladwilliams/Desktop/Accessibility_Website/sassbootstrap/src/scss/style.css:undefined:undefined: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kayladwilliams/Desktop/Accessibility_Website/sassbootstrap/src/scss/style.css'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kayladwilliams/Desktop/Accessibility_Website/sassbootstrap/src/scss/style.css'

Comment: Hopefully thats helpful since I couldn't paste the screenshot of my image

Comment: Does the file sassbootstrap/src/scss/style.css exist?

Comment: Yes, I created that file via Visual Studios. It's in the right directory.

Comment: I would show you my directory if pasting an image was allowed via comments.

Comment: I literally followed along to a video on Linkedln would it help if I sent that link?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Added a tutorial Link and an info about npm init, which could be the solution here.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it. Appreciate it!