# ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir after Angular 12 upgrade

Tags: angular, angular12

Upgrading a large project from Angular 8 to Angular 12...
Now getting this error:
`ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir`

It looks like a similar problem as discussed here: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251645/)
BUT: all of those answers seems to revolve around reinstalling `node-sass`.
I don't have `node-sass` in my solution anymore, because I needed to uninstall it as part of the Angular 12 upgrade (see this question [Angular material: SassError: Invalid CSS after “@include mat”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527236/)

FWIW here are my package.json dependencies. Any ideas?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill": "^1.0.0",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.6.0",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.6.0",
    "@ngxs/router-plugin": "^3.6.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.1",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.12",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.38.1",
    "@turf/boolean-point-in-polygon": "^6.3.0",
    "@turf/difference": "^6.3.0",
    "@turf/helpers": "^6.3.0",
    "@turf/truncate": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.5",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.20",
    "backoff-rxjs": "6.3.2",
    "bowser": "^2.1.0",
    "braintree": "^2.19.0",
    "canvas-toBlob": "^1.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "device": "^0.3.8",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "formdata-polyfill": "^3.0.11",
    "fs-extra": "^4.0.1",
    "geojson-bounds": "^1.0.2",
    "get-user-locale": "^1.1.1",
    "ismobilejs": "^0.4.1",
    "js-yaml": "^3.13.1",
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.3",
    "launchdarkly-js-client-sdk": "^2.12.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "markerwithlabel": "^2.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^8.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ngx-braintree": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.3.0",
    "ngx-uploader": "^7.1.0",
    "nl2br-pipe": "1.1.0",
    "nouislider": "^13.1.3",
    "owasp-password-strength-test": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "siema": "^1.5.1",
    "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.0",
    "tsd-jsdoc": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@google/earthengine": "^0.1.218",
    "@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport": "^1.1.6",
    "@ngx-i18nsupport/tooling": "^8.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-messages": "^1.16.2",
    "@types/chart.js": "2.7.55",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.135",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.12",
    "@types/nouislider": "^9.0.5",
    "@types/siema": "^1.4.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^8.1.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "svgo": "^1.0.5",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4",
    "uglify-js": "^3.6.0"
  },
```

Comment: We have the same problem after upgrading to angular 12 and the "extractLicenses: true" option is triggering this error. I have no idea yet why.

Comment: I already removed all extractLicences: true but the problem stills happening... Another idea?

Comment: Did you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: extractLicenses:true caused issue in my case . Setting false works for me , but no idea why

Answer (score 0):

As a Windows user in a sea of Mac developers, I encountered the same issue. I was able to work around it by setting `extractLicenses` to `false` in my local environment in the `angular.json` file.

Take a look here for more details: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/12317#issuecomment-1275967489